# Chessboard board size

Tags: chessboard

Is it possible to change the size of a \chessboard size. I know it has fixed sizes like tinyboard and so on. But if I just want to scale it down or up by 5%, is that possible?

Comment: What package(s) are you using?

Comment: Yes. You can set boardfontsize to whatever value you want.

Comment: Can I change the size of the labels (a..h and 1..8) as well? I tried to use fontsize, but I can't see any change in label size.

Comment: Yes you can.  And how to do is described in the documention in the section about labels.

Comment: @chessaddict please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 12):

Using `chessboard`, you can set `boardfontsize`; `labelfontsize` will allow changes to the font size for the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}
\begin{document}

{\normallineskip=0pt
\setchessboard{boardfontsize=15pt}
\newchessgame
\chessboard}

{\normallineskip=0pt
\setchessboard{boardfontsize=10pt,labelfontsize=6pt}
\newchessgame
\chessboard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [`skak`](http://ctan.org/pkg/skak), you can scale the output (`\showboard`) using `\scalebox{1.05}` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{skak}% http://ctan.org/pkg/skak
\begin{document}
\fenboard{r5k1/1b1p1ppp/p7/1p1Q4/2p1r3/PP4Pq/BBP2b1P/R4R1K w - - 0 20}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}c}
  100\% & 105\% \\[\bigskipamount]
  \showboard & \scalebox{1.05}{\showboard}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Note that this scales the *entire* chess board, including the indices (rows/columns).

This approach should also work with [`texmate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texmate) since it uses `skak` to produce the boards.